# Interpreting the marginal effect for logit regression when the independent variable log transformed variable

Tags: logistic, probit

I have run probit and logit regression analysis for a model, where the dependent variable is 'Purchase' which takes the value of 1 for purchase, else zero.  The independent variable is the log of distance from the highway. The unit of distance from the highway is in miles. I have calculated the marginal effects:
[image]

I have interpreted the effect as:

A one-mile increase in travel distance from the highway increases the chance of purchase by  0.0099Xln(1.01) = 0.000098 percent (probit regression).

Does my interpretation look correct? If not, how I should explain?

Comment: Logit case is covered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147612/interpretation-of-marginal-effects-in-logit-model-with-log-timesindependent-va/147630#147630) and probit case is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88353/interpreting-the-coefficient-on-a-logged-independent-variable-from-a-probit-mode).

Comment: You can interpret that as saying that a 1% increase in distance is associated with a 0.0099% increase in the probability of purchase (on a [0,100] scale). That's 1/100th of a percent. You can also do it in terms of a 10% increase in distance, which gets you 1/10 of a percent.